# is there any aalternate for ValidatorResourcesInitializer?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have a code to check email validation which is using commons-validator-1.0.2 version, now I want to upgrade the version of commons-validator to 1.4.1 or higher, when I upgrade the jar I am seeing ValidatorResourcesInitializer class is deprecated, do we have any alternate for this class? how can I replace the code which is using ValidatorResourcesInitializer?

```
ValidatorResourcesInitializer.initialize(resources, ins[0], false);
```

and alternate for ValidatorUtil class too

```
ValidatorUtil.getValueAsString(this, idFieldName);
```

Or do we have any alternate jars which I can use to validate e mail which have 4 characters in domain like below:

```
abcd@gmail.email
```

Comment: Hi, I know this question is old, but I'm looking for the alternate for ValidatorUtil.getValueAsString. Have you found it eventually?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
String regex = "^(.+)@(.+)$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abcd@gmail.email");
System.out.println(email +" : "+ matcher.matches());
```

This should be able to validate your email address.

Hope this snippet is helpfull

You could use also the

> Apache Commons Validator

You can get the jar from here

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.5.0

And then in you code you can do something like this:

```
EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid("abcd@gmail.email");
```

Comment: Can't we do with out using regular expression? do we have any other open source jar to use?

Comment: I tried that, but what as some of the classes which are there in 1.0.2 was deprecated we are seeing some issues with ValidatorResourcesInitializer class, what was the alternate for this class in 1.5.0? currently ValidatorResourcesInitializer.initialize(resources, ins[0], false); we are using this in our class can I have an alternate for this in 1.5.0?

Comment: The alternative for ValidatorResourcesInitializer in 1.5.0 is EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid("abcd@gmail.email"); if you need to validate an email address